# why could my website be 'loading' twice?

Tags: php, apache, load-time, pingdom

or at least that's what [pingdom](http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/yLutjsgpN/http://keepyourlinks.com) says, and i think it's a pretty reliable service,

Notes:

1. APACHE: php & mysql
2. No iframes
3. htaccess:

   ```
   #Gzip
   <ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x- javascript application/javascript
   </ifmodule>
   #End Gzip


   # 480 weeks
   <FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|swf)$">
   Header set Cache-Control "max-age=290304000, public"
   </FilesMatch>

   # 1 weeks
   <FilesMatch "\.(js)$">
   Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
   </FilesMatch>

   RewriteEngine On


   ErrorDocument 500 /oohps.php
   ErrorDocument 404 /where.php


   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.keepyourlinks.com [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://keepyourlinks.com/$1 [L,R=301]

   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.keepyourlinks.byethost32.com [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://keepyourlinks.com/$1 [L,R=301]

   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^keepyourlinks.byethost32.com [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://keepyourlinks.com/$1 [L,R=301]

   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^keepyourlinks.com/pre/ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://keepyourlinks.com/$1 [L,R=301]

   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^piscolabis.info$
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/keepyourlinks.com [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://keepyourlinks.com/$1 [L,R=301]


   #Webs Sueltas

   RewriteRule ^facebook-likes$ fbmate.html
   RewriteRule ^api_webmasters$ API.php



   #Options +FollowSymLinks



   RewriteBase /

   RewriteRule ^keep/(.+)/(.+) link1.php?id=$1
   RewriteRule ^article/(.+)/(.+) ?tipo=questions&que=view&id=$1
   RewriteRule ^file/(.+)/(.+) ?tipo=files&que=view&id=$1
   RewriteRule ^user/(.+)/(.+) ?que=usuario&id=$1

   RewriteRule ^categories/(.+)/(.+) listarenlaces.php?id=$1
   ```

I am just looking for possible causes

Comment: why is it making so large highlighting the #comments?

Comment: Just want to note: Apache daemon ignores font size

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet: You need to indent code with 8 spaces instead of just 4 if it's inside a list. Seems to be a bug in the markdown editor that it doesn't do it automatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Has nothing to do with your .htaccess

Perused your site code.  You've got this little bit in your "Last Activity" section:

```
<img src="http://keepyourlinks.com/" width="30" height="30"/>
```

... you're loading your whole page again in an image tag.

More context, to help you find where it's being generated:

```
<div class="comentario">
    <a href="http://keepyourlinks.com/user/736/laroma">
        <img src="http://keepyourlinks.com/" width="30" height="30"/> laroma
    </a>
    <span class="suave"> ha comentado </span>
    <a href="http://keepyourlinks.com/keep/186577/deshidratacion">deshidratacion</a>
    <span class="fecha"> 72 dias:</span>
    <p>
        La deshidratación es la pérdida excesiva de agua respecto al agua que se ingiere. El European Hydration Institute (EHI) es una fundación creada con el fin de avanzar y profundizar en el conocimiento acerca de la hidratación humana y sus efectos sobre la salud, el bienestar y el rendimiento físico y cognitivo.
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: how did you see it? reading the code or did you use some tool? thanks a lot!

Comment: Well, I started off with the assumption that that was the problem (or something similar), so I just did a search for your domain in the source until I found a tag that was attempting to load it improperly.  I made that assumption because it was clearly loading your entire page again without *re*-loading your page, so I knew there had to be some element that was grabbing it.

Comment: This also happens with $.ajax(), and as someone mentioned below, with background:url(); Thanks for the comment, helped me lots

Answer (score 5):

This is old, but I just had a similar problem. The issue was with the css in a div's class. I had a `background:url();` as a placeholder (intending to supply an image later) but forgot about it.

With a blank background url, the page loading twice issue occurs with FF19. I noticed the issue using LiveHTTPheaders. Haven't tested with other browsers/versions. Removing it fixes the issue. Adding it back reintroduces the issue repeatably.

Answer (score 1):

Just want to share my situation with the same problem.

I had forgotten line of code, which created div element with inline style for background image and it used undefined variable:

```
style="background-image: url( <?php echo $image_url ?>)"
```

This printed error message into style instead of url and that element loaded my page second time, so views counters increased by 2 each time. Found it accidently when fixed other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, only "/index.php" and "/" were loading twice every time they were accessed.

This happened because I had the following line in my Virtual Host config file (apache) at "/etc/apache2/sites-available/":

```
<VirtualHost XXX.localhost:80>
    FallbackResource /index.php
</VirtualHost>
```

---

After I removed the "FallbackResource" line, everything worked as expected.
No more double loading for the links/pages I've mentioned above.